# Jquery is not working with Perl in Openwebmail Code Modification

Tags: jquery, perl, autocomplete

I am trying to customise the Openwebmail software for our Organisation.
I have added autocompletion feature in the compose message "TO" field. The Data is being taken from the MySQL database. It is working with mouse events.
The problems are:
1) The navigation keys are not working in the Auto Completion DIV.

I have included jquery files in the perl html generatin file openwebmail-send.pl like this

```
$html= qq|<script language="JavaScript" src="$config{'ow_htmlurl'}/javascript/htmlarea.openwebmail/htmlarea.js"></script>\n|.
        **q*q|<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="$config{'ow_htmlurl'}/javascript/htmlarea.openwebmail/jquery.js"></script>\n|.***
             qq|<script language="JavaScript" src="$config{'ow_htmlurl'}/javascript/htmlarea.openwebmail/dialog.js"></script>\n|.
             qq|<script language="JavaScript" src="$config{'ow_htmlurl'}/javascript/htmlarea.openwebmail/popups/$htmlarealocale/htmlarea-lang.js"></script>\n|.
```

and copied the jquery.js file to the specified location.

2) But the following  Jquery functions for close while click on any other parts of page, is not working.
The error is : $ is not defined

```
The Jquery function is as follows
/*
Function for Close Autocompletion DIV
*/
$("body").click(function(){
     document.getElementById("displaycc").innerHTML="";
});
```

Please help to solve these two problems:

1. Make Jquery to work with the Perl A function to enable up, down,
2. Enter and Tab keys in the Autocompletion DIV

Comment: For 2) replace $ with jQuery like jQuery("body").click(function(){//your code here});

Comment: What are those * signs doing in the Perl script? This does not even compile for me. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Replaced the $ with jQuery("body").click(function(){document.getElementById("displaycc").innerHTML="";
})'. Now the error is "jQuery is not defined"

Comment: The jquery functions are defined in the composemessage.templte, which is an HTML page. So /* is used for commenting. The jquery files are included in the perl page openwebmail.send.pl, which generates the html page.....Thankyou

Comment: The ** in perl is not there . sorry it has come by mistake. The perl script is like this  $html= qq|<script language="JavaScript" src="$config{'ow_htmlurl'}/javascript/htmlarea.openwebmail/htmlarea.js"></script>\n|.
  qq|<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="$config{'ow_htmlurl'}/javascript/htmlarea.openwebmail/jquery.js"></script>\n|.

Answer (score 0):

the openwebmail beta already has auto-completion in the To: Cc: and Bcc: fields. Why re-invent the wheel?

http://openwebmail.acatysmoof.com

check the Current Development Demo.